# Kotlin Smart Casting generic type by smartcasting argument

Tags: kotlin, casting

I am trying to achieve something analagous to the following toy example:

```
fun getBoolean() = true
fun getFloat() = 1.0F
fun getInt() = 1
fun getLong() = 1L
fun getString() = "foobar"

fun <T> extract(defaultVal: T): T = when (defaultVal) {
    is Boolean -> getBoolean() as T
    is Float -> getFloat() as T
    is Int -> getInt() as T
    is Long -> getLong() as T
    is String -> getString() as T
    else -> defaultVal
}
```

Is there a way to achieve this without the unchecked cast `as T` in the different cases?

Removing the unchecked casts results in a compiler error whereby the return type is the type of the function, and not `T`.  I feel like the compiler should be able to infer `T` by the `defaultVal is ____` in the `when` statement here in a similar way to smart casting:

```
fun usesInt(arg: Int) = arg + 1

fun <T> extract(defaultVal: T): T = when (defaultVal) {
    // ...
    is Int -> {
        usesInt(defaultVal)  // defaultVal is smart cast to Int => T is Int
        getInt() as T
    }
    // ...
}
```

Is this a shortcoming in the smart cast/inference system, or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, that would be an invalid assumption to make when casting. Consider this:

```
open class Base
class Derived: Base()

fun getBoolean() = true
fun getBase() = Base()

fun <T> extract(defaultVal: T): T = when (defaultVal) {
    is Boolean -> getBoolean() as T
    is Base -> getBase() as T
    else -> defaultVal
}
```

Then if you do this:

```
val extracted: Derived = extract(Derived())
```

You'll get a ClassCastException because it's trying to cast a Base to a Derived.

I suppose they could make it more sophisticated and check if the classes are `open` or not, but this would be stepping through a lot of logic. If it was this sophisticated in all areas, I think compilation would be super slow.

Secondly, casting to a generic type is always going to give you an unchecked cast warning  since generic types can't be checked at all. The alternative is making the function `inline` and the type `reified`. Then it's not an unchecked cast, but you will still get a ClassCastException if you make the mistake above.

Comment: Brilliant thank you, I was only thinking about primitive types (due to the use case this came up with).  If one were to suppose there were some generic type constraint for primitive types do you think this could theoretically be possible, or would the same rules about casting to a generic type apply?

Comment: Are you asking if the smart-casting would be possible? It looks possible to me now not just for primitives but for any final class, just possibly more sophisticated than is practical.